# mock BeanUtils.setProperty to throw an exception

Tags: java, mocking, mockmvc

I have class `A` with a public `foo` function, that using a private `boo` function that uses `BeanUtils.setProperty`.

I want to test the scenario when `setProperty` will throw an exception (`IllegalAccessException`, `InvocationTargetException`, it doesn't matter).

I did a `@Mock` on `BeanUtils`, `@InjectMocks` on class `A`, and tried the following:

```
doThrow(new IllegalAccessException()).when(beanUtils).getProperty(any(),any(),any());
```

But I get the warning:

> Static member 'org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.getProperty(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)' accessed via instance reference" and the exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No bean specified" when running.